# PyInstallerを使ってPythonファイルの単一実行ファイルを作成し、ffmpegをsubprocessで実行したい

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pyinstaller

PyInstallerを使ってPythonのファイルを単一実行ファイルにし、subprocessモジュールでFFmpegとFFproveを実行したいと考えています。myapp.specファイルでbinariesにそれぞれ指定して利用したいのですが、どうやって実行すればよいのか教えていただきたいです。

各ファイルの説明
・myapp.py (単一実行ファイルにしたいPythonファイル)
・myapp.app (単一実行ファイル)
・myapp.spec (pyinstllerでmyapp.pyからmyapp.appを作成する際の設計書)

#### myapp.specファイルのbinaries

```
binaries=[('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg', '.'), ('/usr/local/bin/ffprobe', '.')]
```

#### myapp.pyでのFFproveの実行の例

```
subprocess.run(["ffprove", "-i", video_path, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

## 環境

MacOS 10.15.7

Python 3.6
PyInstaller 3.6
FFmpeg 4.3.1

## 試したこと

myapp.appファイルの中身を見てみると、myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/にffmpegとffproveの実行形式ファイルのコピーが作られていたので、myapp.appファイルの絶対pathがわかっていれば実行できました。

#### /Applications/myapp.appとわかっている場合

```
subprocess.run(["/Applications/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/ffprobe", video, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

どこにmyapp.appがあっても実行できないと困るので、myapp.pyでmyapp.appの絶対パスを取得しようとしたのですが、取得する簡単な方法がわかりませんでした。

myapp.pyでos.getcwd()を出力させると、myapp.appがどこにあろうとルートディレクトリになってしまい、myapp.appの絶対パスはわかりませんでした。

#### 現在のwork directory

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
# cwdは常に"/"になっている
```

globを使えばわかりそうなのですが、とても時間がかかってしまいます。

#### globでmyapp.appの絶対パスを取得する(時間がかかってしまう)

```
myapp_path = glob.glob('/**/myapp.app', recursive=True)
```

Comment: この記事が参考になるのでは？[python: MacOSでappにした状態で、appのフルパスを取得する方法について](https://teratail.com/questions/87569)

Comment: kunifさん、ありがとうございます！解決できました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://teratail.com/questions/87569
コメントで紹介していただいた上記のサイトで解決いたしました。
sys.argv[0]またはsys.executableで実行ファイルまでの絶対パスが取得できました。

## 絶対パスが/Applications/myapp.appだった場合

```
print(sys.argv[0]) # 出力 /Aplications/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp
print(sys.executable) # 出力 /Aplications/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp
# 最後の/myappはmyapp.pyの実行形式ファイル
```

ありがとうございました。誰かのお役に立てれば幸いです。